# How can I have Karma tests in the same folder as other Angular components, and have them run last?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Assume I have a project directory which looks something like this:

```
comments.component.js
comments.component.spec.js
comments.controller.js
comments.controller.spec.js
comments.service.js
comments.service.spec.js
```

The spec files are Karma tests.

### The spec files are in the same folder as the Angular components

For organisational reasons I want to be able to put my tests right next to the code under test. I don't want to put it off in a separate spec folder.

With Gulp, composing a glob would be easy, something like this:

```
[ '*.js', '!*.spec.js', '*.spec.js' ]
```

However, this doesn't work in Karma. If I do this:

```
files: [
  './source/js/**/*.js',
  '!./source/js/**/*.spec.js',
  './source/js/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

This line: `'!./source/js/**/*.spec.js'` matches no files.

### The Question

How can I compose a karma.conf.js file such that all my angular components are included first, and all my spec files are included next, without hiding all my spec files away in a separate folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way if you want to avoid creating another folder:

```
files: [
  './source/js/**/*.service.js',
  './source/js/**/*.component.js',
  './source/js/**/*.controller.js',
  './source/js/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

Comment: Well that is a functional solution, and indeed moderately elegant :)

Comment: Not sure if that will work but I don't see why not. Can you please provide me a feedback on this?

Comment: Hi @SonnY, that will definitely work, but would require quite a big code reorganisation, which I was hoping to avoid. It might we worth it all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your karma file should only be:

```
files: [
  './source/js/**/*.js'
]
```

because you want to use all the JavaScript files inside your `js` folder

Comment: Hi @SonnY, Yes and no. Order of inclusion matters in this case. I need to include everything matching '**/*.spec.js' last of all. As I mentioned, with Gulp this would be easy because Gulp allows you to modify the pipeline.

Comment: yes but you cannot include everything in the first place, remove the test files and re-include them.

Comment: You can either create a test file inside your `js` folder and set your Karma like this:

    files: [
      './source/js/**/*.js'
    ]

Or, you can try something like this:

    files: [
      './source/js/**/*.component.js',
      './source/js/**/*.controller.js',
      './source/js/**/*.service.js',
      './source/js/**/*.spec.js'
    ]

Comment: Yes, and how do I remove the test files and reinclude them if they are in the same directory? This is the crux of the question.

Comment: Thanks @Sonny - It would be easy to put the tests in a different folder, but for organisation reasons I would like to put them next to the code under test.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered something related to your question today. I had a look inside the official Angular-seed GitHub repo and their Karma configuration file looks like this one:

```
files : [
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/components/**/*.js',
  'app/view*/**/*.js'
],
```

So it seems you don't have to care about including the source code first and the tests files at the end of the "files" array.
Here is the link: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/karma.conf.js